# CSS "and" selector - Can I select elements that have multiple classes?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to select all of the elements that have both `.checked` and `.featured` tags. So basically, what I'm looking for is an "and" selector; I don't know if there is one or not.

Is there any workaround for cases like this?

Comment: is there css collections selector like this `.main [:hover,ul,ul>li,p] { display:inline-block;}`

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You use both (*without space between them*)

```css
.checked.featured{
   // ...
}
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#class-html

---

Example

```css
div{margin:1em;padding:1em;}

.checked{color:green;}
.featured{border:1px solid #ddd;}

.checked.featured{
       font-weight:bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="checked">element with checked class</div>
<div class="featured">element with featured class</div>
<div class="featured checked">element with both checked and featured classes</div>
```

Comment: Sitepoint's reference seems a little easier to grok (IMO, obviously): http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/classselector

Comment: is there a similar way to join two ID selectors like that? 
I tried #pie#bars table {}  (two tables in two different IDs). But that does not work.

Comment: @MakanTayebi what you describe is multiple selectors. Just use a comma with the full selector each time. `#pie table, #bars table {}`

Comment: So '.checked.featured' only selects items that have both classes?

Comment: @MakanTayebi yes, that is what the original question is about.

Comment: @EdwardBlack , what do you mean exactly ? If you mean to apply it to `h4` and `h5` elements that have both classes then `h4.checked.featured, h5.checked.featured{...}` you need to use `,` for multiple selectors

Answer (score 19):

You can just "join" two classes like that: `.checked.featured`

Answer (score 11):

To express AND you simply concatenate your classes `.checked.featured` which may not be confused with the popular `.checked .featured` which is the descendant selector.

Have a look at the official [Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)

Comment: is there css collections selector like this `.main [:hover,ul,ul>li,p] { display:inline-block;`

Comment: @Muhammad take a look at the css4 selector [:matches()](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches)