# CSS Selector "AND" when using div/span

Tags: css, selector

I want to select elemtents matches two classes using span:

```
.class1 *AND* .class2 span div.class3:nth-child(even)
```

The question ist similar to this one:
[CSS "and" selector - Can I select elements that have multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599218/css-and-selector)

but I do not use just classes, but also span elements, so this do not work (I think it searches for elements containing the right expression and belong to class1 AND class2.):

```
.class1.class2 span div.class3:nth-child(even)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is your current HTML?

Comment: Buddy, I see you are very lost... You should start by learning how to set up the selectors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: I am using still html 4, and yes I am a little bit lost, its my second week using css :( Thanks for the link. Nevertheless the Problem exists still...

Answer (score 0):

This may suit your needs:

```
.class1 span div.class3:nth-child(even), .class2 span div.class3:nth-child(even)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the comma is a logical OR, it selects all elemtents fitting the first expression and all elements fitting the second expression. I want to select just elemtens fitting both expressions at the same time.