# center logo responsive two classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I administrative a site where there is a logo which is left aligned.

The HTML and CSS for that logo is looking like this:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="logo-container">
        <a href="@homePage.Url">
            <img src="/img/logo-white.svg" data-svg-fallback="/img/logo-white.png" alt="@logoAltText" class="img-responsive logo"/>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
@mixin img-responsive($display: block) {
  display: $display;
  max-width: 100%; // Part 1: Set a maximum relative to the parent
  height: auto; // Part 2: Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching
}
```

I have to make a Landingpage where the logo is centered. Therefore I thought on my landingpage I could do like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo-container">
    <a href="@homePage.Url">
       <img src="/img/logo-white.svg" data-svg-fallback="/img/logo-white.png" alt="@logoAltText" class="landingpage img-responsive logo"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.landingpage img-responsive logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

is that incorrect?

Comment: use this .landingpage.img-responsive.logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a multi-class event, remove the spaces between the class selectors:

```
.landingpage.img-responsive.logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

`margin: 0 auto;` is a good way to center a block-level element that is smaller than it's container element. However depending on your markup you may want to use `text-align: center;` on the parent.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The HTML should still be: class="landingpage img-responsive logo, right?

Comment: It is still not working, so maybe there is some inherit. Could a hack be to make a new logo img, and then use my css for this? I just set a border around the logo in the same class, and that is comming fine. But the logo is still not centered.

Comment: Yes in the HTML attribute, the classes are space seperated `class="landingpage img-responsive logo"`. To really help you and identify the problem, we need to see an example page with your whole markup

Answer (score 0):

img-responsive is a class, therefore you must use it with a `.` . `.img-responsive` and `.logo` and `.landingpage` are in the same class so you should remove space like this :

```
.landingpage.img-responsive.logo{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

See the [element element selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) and the [And selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599218/css-and-selector)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The HTML should still be: class="landingpage img-responsive logo, right?

Comment: Yes, but if it's not working you may check if an other css property took down this one.